# Question on the proof that totally bounded and complete implies sequentially compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm browsing the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109555/470546) on showing that if a metric space is totally bounded and complete then it is sequentially compact. I'm confused about two claims.

First, the proof says :

> For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $D_n$ be a finite subset of $X$ such that the open
>   balls of radius $2^{−n}$ centred at the points of $D_n$ cover $X$.

Why does $D_n$ have to be finite? I know that's implied from the definition of totally boundedness. I guess my question is really why can't we let $D_n$ be infinite?

Second question (which is related to the first I think):

> $D_0$  is finite, so there is a point $y \in D_0$ such that infinitely
>   many terms of $\sigma$ are in $B(y_0,1)$

Why would $B(y_0,1)$ contain infinitely many terms? What if the metric space X is finite in the first place?

Comment: Think pigeonhole principle: you put infinitely many balls into a finite number of pots, so one pot has to have infinitely many. If $X$ is finite, then it is automatically sequentially compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D_n $ wasn't finite you couldn't conclude that infinitely many elements of  $\sigma $ are contained in one element of  $D_n $ (there could be one in each, for instance )...

Secondly  $\sigma $ is a sequence,  hence has infinitely many terms, some or all of which may be equal  (such as when  $X $ is finite)...