# proof of totally bounded and complete $\implies$ compact ($1/2^n$ vs $1/n$ radius open balls)

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109550/totally-bounded-complete-implies-compact) has a proof of that fact, and I was thinking if it is necessary to impose $1/2^n$ as the shrinking radius of the balls. Why not just $1/n$?

Comment: That's just a choice, it is not important. It seems to me that, in this case, any sequence that tends to 0 will do.